# Account icon is not displayed in the contact list on Android 5

Tags: android, icons, integration, contacts, account

I created a SyncAdapter for app and did his integration with the contacts list using the following code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactRefIms = operationList.size();

// Create our RawContact
ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, contact.getName());
operationList.add(builder.build());

// Create a Data record of common type 'StructuredName'
RawContact builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactRefIms); 
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,contact.getName());
operationList.add(builder.build());

// Create a Data record of custom type
builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactRefIms); 
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.myapp.profile");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contact.getName());
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "MyApp");
builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "View contact!");
operationList.add(builder.build());

try {
    contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(Const.TAG_LOG, "Fail on integrate contact!", e);
}
```

I also put this information in the manifest:

> ```
>     <activity
>         android:name="com.myapp.view.activity.CallActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.myapp.profile" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> ```

With this, the app was showing the account icon (the SyncAdapter) and my application information in synchronized contacts in the contact list and QuickContactBadge. Here's an example (I did not include here the code and manifest used to create the SyncService and SyncAdapter because not think it's necessary):

[Contact with app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amjvf.jpg)

But with Android 5 my app icon is not displayed. Here's an example:

[contact without app icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77dRV.jpg)

Comment: What does your @xml/syncadapter and @xml/contacts look like?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find any solution ?